# am i using @font face incorrectly?

Tags: html, css

can anyone tell me why i cant seem to get a font to work on my site

css

```css
@fontface {
    font-family: Summer;
    src: url(/font/CodePredators-Regular.ttf);
}

p { 
     color: #000000;
     font-size: 1em;
     font-family: Summer, Tahoma, "Tungsten Bold", Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<p>this is a test</p>
```

ive actually tried a couple other "methods" but nothing seems to work
ive even tried to upload the font into the root folder in an attempt to make the url path easier

nothing gives

maybe if i see some different code it will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a typo, missing a `-` between @Font and Face,

Anyhow, his is how you should use `@font-face`  correctly (using Google Fonts sample)

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Open Sans'), local('OpenSans'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v13/cJZKeOuBrn4kERxqtaUH3VtXRa8TVwTICgirnJhmVJw.woff2) format('woff2');
}
```

---

#### Snippet

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Open Sans'), local('OpenSans'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v13/cJZKeOuBrn4kERxqtaUH3VtXRa8TVwTICgirnJhmVJw.woff2) format('woff2');
}
p {
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Tahoma, "Tungsten Bold", Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<p>this is a test</p>
```

Comment: ARRRGGGGG ..... how did i miss that?? smh

thanks dippas